# How to access the static values of a class having only a reference of type Class to this class

Tags: java, class, static

Considering the class A:

```
public class A {
    public static final CONSTANT = "i am a static final member";
}
```

and having a variable of type `Class` that references the `A` class:

```
Class c = A.class;
```

how can I access `CONSTANT` using the `c` variable, without building an instance of class `A`:

```
 // all these will certainly not work
c.CONSTANT;
c.getStatic().CONSTANT;
```

Comment: `c.getField("CONSTANT").get(null)` I reckon. I would also suggest that you don't use rawtypes.

Comment: @sotirios-delimanolis I would like a solution without reflection to still use the compile time checks. `"CONSTANT"` is something I would not use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [java reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to acquire such information at runtime.
Reflection allows you for example to inspect any **fields** that belong to any class object.

In your case, the field is **public** and **static**, therefore the following code

```
String constantValue = c.getField("CONSTANT").get(null);
```

will work.

(getField() searches public fields; and get() needs an "object" to work on; but for static fields, the parameter doesn't matter; so it can be null)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the value of `CONSTANT` would be:

```
c.getDeclaredField("CONSTANT").get(null)
```

From the `Field.get` doc:

> If the underlying field is a static field, the obj argument is ignored; it may be null.